# Rotate boxplot legend (R, ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using the following code.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
 mtcars <- mtcars[!(mtcars$carb==6 | mtcars$carb==8),]
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
 guides(fill = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal"))
```

This results in:

[image]

I would like to rotate the legend to obtain this desired result:

[image]

Might anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Try `... +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
           title.position = "bottom",
           label.position = "top",
           label.vjust = 1,
           label.theme = element_text(angle = 90),
           title.theme = element_text(angle = 90)))`

Comment: Ah, thank you, @AntoniosK. I just posted a very similar answer. Looks like I only used `reverse` in addition. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out following a suggestion by @LFischer. There is probably an easier way, but after some trial and error, this did it for me:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
 mtcars <- mtcars[!(mtcars$carb==6 | mtcars$carb==8),]
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
 guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, direction = "vertical", label.position = "top", label.theme = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5), title.position = "bottom", title.theme = element_text(angle = 90)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put it on the top

```
library(ggplot2)
 mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
 mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
 mtcars <- mtcars[!(mtcars$carb==6 | mtcars$carb==8),]
 ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: example_img]

Or you can make it vertical

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$carb <- as.factor(mtcars$carb)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
mtcars <- mtcars[!(mtcars$carb==6 | mtcars$carb==8),]
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = carb, y = mpg, fill = am), 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical")
```

[image: example_img_2]

Hope it helps

Comment: Sure, that works @LFischer. However, unfortunately, I need it to be on the right, as per provided image. Thank you for your suggestion, though.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez I updated my response to better suit your needs. The "am" legend text is not in your desired position but I argue that this display is better yet (: Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I like your second option better, but I still hoped for the last bit to be adjusted too. I will try using your second suggestion. In trying to get there myself before posting my question, I found a way to rotate the text only, so maybe I can add that in and then it is pretty close. Thank you. If it works, I'll add the result here too.

Comment: Yes I belive you can do it with `element_text(angle = 90)`so it would be `theme(legend.direction = "vertical", legend.title = element_text(angle = 90))` but I don't think it'll be quite what you're hoping for. I hope you figure it out and share with us after!

Comment: Thanks again @LFischer. See my added answer, which worked for me. Thank you for your help.